# Regular expression in python

Tags: python

I have text file (seq.fasta) which contains sequence as follows

```
M1

MPMILGYWNVRGLTHPIRMLLEYTDSSYDEKRYTMGDAPDFDRSQWLNEKFKLGLDFPNL
PYLIDGSHKITQSNAILRYLARKHHLDGETEEERIRADIVENQVMDTRMQLIMLCYNPDF
EKQKPEFLKTIPEKMKLYSEFLGKRPWFAGDKVTYVDFLAYDILDQYRMFEPKCLDAFPN
LRDFLARFEGLKKISAYMKSSRYIATPIFSKMAHWSNK
```

I have to extract motif PXXP exactly 4 characters (XX can be any characters).

I tried following code:

```
import re

infile=open("seq.fasta",'r')

out=open("out.csv",'w')

for line in infile:

   line = line.strip("\n")

   if line.startswith('>'):

      name=line

   else:

      motif = re.compile(r"(\bP{2}P\b)")

      c = line.count('motif')

      print '%s:%s' %(name,c)

      out.write('%s:%s\n' %(name,c))
```

But it is not finding motif.

Comment: There is no string `P..P` in the provided input above (here `.` stands for "any character"). Don't get the question. Please update with expected output. You're regexp say to look for a wordboundary, followed by 2Ps, followed by a P and then a wordboundary

Comment: @Fredrik The `P..P` string appears split across the first two lines. Presumably, the entire string is intended to represent a line from the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
re.compile( r"(P[\w]{2}P)" )
```

or

```
re.compile( r"(P[A-Z]{2}P)" )
```

Meta **\w** - means alphanumeric characters, similar to [A-Z0-9_]

Answer (score 5):

Try with this one:

```
 re.compile(r"(P..P)")
```

`.` means any character.

`{2}` means that the last token must be repeated twice times (in your regex, this means `PP`.

`\b` matches word boundaries